Remove event scroll to top when clicked option in selectpicker
I have a select with class select-picker in jquery.
<select class="form-control select-picker" name="tags[]" id="tags" data-live-search="true" multiple="true">

If I do scroll down below of this select and click it, or click in one option from this select, webpage do scrolling to top.
I need to disable this event and I don't know how can I solve this.
I'm trying this codes, with bad result (not disable event, scroll to top):
$('.select-picker').on('changed.bs.select', function(e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
      $("body").scrollTop(0);

}); // this code not run

e.offset().top; // This code not run.

e.off('scroll'); //This code not run.

$(window).off('scroll'); // this code not run

e.preventDefault(); // this code not run

This block also does not work:
$(this).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop()-e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
e.stopPropagation();
e.preventDefault();

I don't know that I'm doing wrong.
I share short video:
https://www.veed.io/view/2105526e-563f-46f2-b55e-e922a4646a9d?panel=share

the scenario you are talking about is very unclear. It might shed some light if you shared a live snippet exactly reproducing the issue.. because trying to have a select like that after including all the required assets (bootstrap js/css and jquery) it's still not enough to trigger the case you described as: if i do scroll down below of this select and click it, or click in one option from this select, webpage to do scrolling to top.

@DiegoD thanks for your response. I shared a link with short video

that's not enough.. anyway this is a basic scenario having a working bootstrap select https://jsfiddle.net/w93hea6z/ ... this is something  you had to do if you wanted people to save time while helping you. The behaviour is more or less the same execpt that what is scrolled to top is the select itself and not its container. Anyway I have no idea how to prevent that.. naybe a better approach would be having a size showing only the options that can be fit inside the viewport to avoid the whole problem entirely.
